# Web API 2 Action with String array as GET parameter not working as expected

Tags: arrays, parameters, get, asp.net-web-api2, action

I have an action which looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Search for customers/projects/tasks by title.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="q">The query to search by.</param>
/// <param name="filters">Extra filters for the search query.</param>
[Route("Search")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSearch(string[] filters, string q = "")
{
    ...
}
```

According to the information I could find, I should be able to pass values to the `filters` parameter by using a url similar to this:

```
http://application/controller/Search?q=query&filters=first&filters=second
```

Unfortunately for me, when I try to access the `filters` parameter inside this action, it is always `null`.

**EDIT:**
When viewing the api Help pages in my application, it is only showing `q` as URI parameter.

The `filters` parameter seems to be recognized as a body parameter.

[Help page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OddEY.png)

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this behavior and how I could fix it? (How I can make the `filters` parameter be recognized as a URI parameter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the solution here was to change the action to this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSearch([FromUri] string[] filters, string q = "")
{
    ...
}
```

The `[FromUri]` in front of a parameter forces the parameter to be taken from the URI, instead of the body.